# HEAD request from Trello API to Heroku app not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, trello

I am trying to make a webhook for my trello account. Below is the ruby code.

```
callbackurl=root_url + 'cards'
response= HTTParty.post("https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/#{Rails.application.secrets.trello_user_key}/webhooks/?key=#{Rails.application.secrets.trello_api_key}&idModel=#{@tunnel.from_list_id}&callbackURL=#{callbackurl}")
```

This essentially authenticate with my app's `api_key` and user token and create a webhook with the call back URL specified. When I hard code the appropriate Heroku app `root_url` and run this code on local machine it works. But when I deploy it and run the code it doesn't work. It returns an error

```
URL (https://thawing-tundra-5116.herokuapp.com/cards) not reachable. Error: ETIMEDOUT
```

This seems very odd. The URL exists. Can anyone explain me why this is happening? As per Trello API, a HEAD request should return 200 and it does.

Comment: if you have free plan on heroku it blocks network requests as far as i know

Comment: my app recieves trello http post requests . Its just this head request that  shows an error.

Comment: Is your URL a `https://thawing-tundra-5116.herokuapp.com/cards` accessible on internet so that Trello can reach it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself. The request from heroku to trello , to app took too much time , so heroku aborted it. It was mainly because I was using webrick in production. Changed it to puma and things are fine.